# How do I extract HTML content using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, extract, html-content-extraction

I know, i know... regex is not the best way to extract HTML text. But I need to extract article text from a lot of pages, I can store regexes in the database for each website. I'm not sure how XML parsers would work with multiple websites. You'd need a separate function for each website.

In any case, I don't know much about regexes, so bear with me.

I've got an HTML page in a format similar to this

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <div class=nav>...</div><p id="someshit" />
    <div class=body>....</div>
    <div class=footer>...</div>
</body>
```

I need to extract the contents of the body class container.

I tried this.

```
$pattern = "/<div class=\"body\">\(.*?\)<\/div>/sui"
$text = $htmlPageAsIs;
if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches))
    echo "MATCHED!";
else
    echo "Sorry gambooka, but your text is in another castle.";
```

What am I doing wrong? My text ends up in another castle.

*EDIT: ooohh... never mind, I found [readability's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146934/create-great-parser-extract-relevant-text-from-html-blogs)

Comment: Obviously, you haven't read SO's most upvoted answer, yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 . If you don't know much about regexes *and* about XML parsers, why start with regexes and not with the more useful approach of HTML parsing?

Comment: Does that DIV contain any other sub-DIVs?

Comment: @Boldewyn, I did, i visualized that guy hunting me with a pitchfork while writing down this question. But I don't understand how i could scan multiple websites with XML parser.

Comment: Use a HTML/XML parser and store a single <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp">XPath</a> path per website.

Comment: Well you could always store the XPath expressions.

Comment: An interesting picture to imagine ;-) However, he *is* right, you will have a hard time unleashing regexes to arbitrary HTML. Even if it works with your test data, someone might insert a tag here or append an attribute there, and your craftfully tailored regex is paying its dept to nature.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching for `class="body"` your document has `class=body`: you're missing the quotes. Use `"/<div class=\"?body\"?>(.*?)<\/div>/sui"`.

Comment: And yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: That's one thing, but he also forgot to escape the quotes (you as well), since the whole string block is wrapped in the same type of quotes.

Comment: Noooooooo! No more references to that! It's an awesome answer and everything, but the constant references to that question are getting as old as Jon Skeet facts.

Comment: The original HTML does have quotes. I wrote that down as an example. In any case, my bad. I should've been clearer.

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't escape the brackets.

Comment: @karim79 As long as they keep asking :D

Comment: @karim79: Only Jon Skeet is allowed to post links to that question.