# Regex - PHP :: Regex pattern to parse links and images from html page

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I extract HTML content using Regex in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818584/how-do-i-extract-html-content-using-regex-in-php)
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Hi,

I dont know regex, i working with PHP (possible use Zend framework)

I need to get from html page images and links.
I think the best way to do it with regex, regex pattern that  insert images and links to 2 arrays:

1. linksArray
2. imagesArray

Please can you help me,

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML.  Use an HTML parser. http://us2.php.net/dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before. Quite often ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661179/regex-php-match-all-links-with-specific-text)). Regexes are a bad solution. You should use a parser.